# When I run flutter project this show error that Dart compiler exited unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, dart

Wrong full snapshot version, expected '8ee4ef7a67df9845fba331734198a953' found '953aa80d78c4d8886e3e4d784fd9d95f'

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

Comment: Which platform you  use ?

Comment: Android studio @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: Ok If you use Mac OS go to Flutter>bin> and delete cache folder inside this directory and re run your project

Comment: still have same error @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: If you delete cache folder run flutter upgrade then flutter doctor and run your project